# Metronome for Gnome desktop

Tags: music

Does anybody know about a metronome that resembles a real one? Look at this online version http://simple.bestmetronome.com/ That is exactly what I am looking for, but installable instead of online. Thnx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find a metronome for music practice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814759/where-can-i-find-a-metronome-for-music-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the simple `gtick` application:

[image]

I does not provide an animated picture of a real metronome but does the job.

From a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gtick
```

Comment: Actually, I have already downloaded that one, as well as gtklick, both of them do the job.

Comment: haha sure dude, I knew about that one but at least you showed some interest on my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GNOME Metronome](https://apps.gnome.org/app/com.adrienplazas.Metronome/).

[image]
 <sub>GNOME Metronome on Kubuntu 22.04.</sub>

It is available on the official repositories.

```
sudo apt install gnome-metronome
```

The latest version is available on Flatpak.

```
flatpak install flathub com.adrienplazas.Metronome
```